# iOS Change iAD banner size in iPad detail split view

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, iad

I have a problem with the iAD banners in an iPad App that uses splitView.
I would like to put the banner in the detail view in landscape mode, but the banner is cropped to the right side. Is there a way to resize it, maybe making it smaller to keep the aspect ratio?

Tho show the banner I've used the standard code.

In the .h file

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

and in the .m file:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

I'm adding a screenshot to show the situation:
[image]

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this same thing. I know that I can make the ad expand all the way across, but I would like it to display only for the detail view. Did you find a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I found another question here for this topic as I now have to deal with the same problem. Unfortunately that question is a little bit old:

[how to add an adbannerview to a UISplitviewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734578/how-to-add-an-adbannerview-to-a-uisplitviewcontroller)

As an example one could take one of the answers there with a link to iAdSuite where you have plenty of examples, how to programmatically solve this problem (back in 2011):

[iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)

There is also a try there to make it with a storyboard, but it's not that up-to-date as I quickly see it.

Hope this helps and if you find a nice solution, please post it here! :)